# iOS8 difference between launch image and image for launch file

Tags: xcode, image, ios8, constraints

The human interface guidelines for iOS 8 give these instructions:

> If you need to use static launch images, you create images in
>   different sizes for different devices. Static launch images for all
>   devices must include the status bar region. For specific measurements,
>   see Table 39-1.
>
> Although it’s best to use a launch file for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6
>   Plus, you can instead supply static launch images if necessary. If you
>   need to create static launch images for these devices, use the
>   following sizes:
>
> For iPhone 6:
>
> 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait 
>   1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape
>
> For iPhone 6 Plus:
>
> 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait 
>   2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

All right.  That I get.

But when I go to create a launch file, there's a view controller--and that view controller needs an image.

What dimensions are that image?

Are they the dimensions Apple lists above?  If so,

1. why say you should only use them if you're using a static launch file, and
2. do you use the dimensions for the 6 or the 6+?  Or the 5?

Note:  I see that constraints are involved, and I SUCK at using constraints, but I think the question is valid anyway.

Comment: Well you could just some multiple images in the launch nib and make them scale correctly using autolayout. Or just one logo in the middle of the view and make it stay in the center. Or you can even use the old layout mask.

Comment: What the apple website is talking about is the image sizes that you would need to put into the Images.xcassets file where you have the folder "LaunchImages". If you are transferring an old Xcode project, then right click in Images.xcassets to create a new LaunchImages folder, where all the new possible launch image sizes will be listed.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you leave this as an answer so I can accept it?